# Oracle Forms - Error 103, Encountered the symbol “SELECT”

Tags: database, oracle, oracleforms

hi i got error 103 line 7, column 1
can you help me?, this my code:

```
INSERT INTO KARYAWAN VALUES (:TXT_NAMA_KARYAWAN,:TXT_ID_KARYAWAN);
COMMIT;


DECLARE
    CURSOR 
    IS SELECT NAMA_KARYAWAN,ID_KARYAWAN
    FROM KARYAWAN;

BEGIN
    GO_BLOCK('KARYAWAN');
    OPEN UWU;
    LOOP
        FETCH UWU INTO :NAMA_KARYAWAN,
                       :ID_KARYAWAN;

    EXIT WHEN UWU %NOTFOUND;
    NEXT_RECORD;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE UWU;
    FIRST_RECORD;

END;
```

yesterday when i was in campus the query worked fine, data can be saved and can be shown on the tabular table, but after i took home and compile the error code show up again...   i am using oracle form builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing cursor name in declaration, add `UWU` after `CURSOR`:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR UWU
    IS SELECT NAMA_KARYAWAN,ID_KARYAWAN
    FROM KARYAWAN;
```

See [Cursor Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/cursor_declaration.htm):
[image]